# Code not running inside a React component

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-router, use-effect

I'm creating a React app and I'm trying to protect some routes behind password authorization.

My component to handle this is the following :

(ProtectedRoute.js)

```js
export default function ProtectedRoute({ code, redirect_path = '/login' }) {

    if (code === 401) return <Navigate to={redirect_path} replace/>;
    return <Outlet/>;

}
```

All I need to do is pass the HTTP status code returned by my back-end and if it corresponds to an unauthorized response then it asks the user to log in, otherwise they are allowed through.

I query my back-end from `App.js` in the following way :

(App.js)

```js
export default function App() {

    let [status, setStatus] = useState(401);
    useEffect(() => {
        fetch(
            'http://localhost:5000/auth',
            {
                method: 'GET',
                mode: 'cors',
                headers: {
                    'id_token': sessionStorage.getItem('id_token')
                }
            }
        )
            .then(response => response.status)
            .then(status => setStatus(status));
    }, []);
    console.log('status=' + status);

    return (
        <div className="App">
            <Navbar is_logged_in={status === 200}/>
            <ToastContainer/>
            <Routes>
                <Route index element={<Home/>}/>
                <Route path="/vehicle/:id" element={<EV/>}/>
                <Route element={<ProtectedRoute code={status}/>}>
                    <Route path="/add" element={<AddEV/>}/>
                </Route>
                <Route path="/filter" element={<Home/>}/>
                <Route path="/compare" element={<Home/>}/>
                <Route path="/login" element={<LoginRegister type="login"/>}/>
                <Route path="/register" element={<LoginRegister type="register"/>}/>
                <Route path="/logout" element={<Logout/>}/>
                <Route path="*" element={<p>Nothing here: 404!</p>}/>
            </Routes>
        </div>
    );
}
```

This works, except for one problem. When the user is sent to the login page and successfully authenticates, they are then sent back to the index. At this point, I would expect the code inside the `useEffect` hook to fire and update the value of `status`.

Instead nothing happens. If I manually refresh the page then the code is triggered and everything happens the way I'd expect it to.

Clearly the idea is correct but the implementation is wrong. Is what I want to achieve possible ? If so how should I go about it ?

Thanking you in advance for your suggestions.

Comment: The `useEffect` has an empty dependency, so it runs only once when the `App` component mounts. This is why it "works" when you reload the page. It reloads the app, i.e. remounts `App` component and the `useEffect` hook callback is invoked. When exactly, and how often, do you want this `"/auth"` API to be called? On every access to a protected route? Or just when logging in/out to set the `status` state?

Comment: Ideally, every time the user visits the `/` URL. If that is not possible then whenever logging in/out should be enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `useEffect` has an empty dependency, so it runs only once when the `App` component mounts. This is why it "works" when you reload the page. It reloads the app, i.e. remounts `App` component and the `useEffect` hook callback is invoked.

It is common to abstract "auth" state into a React Context, to be accessed by the app where necessary, like when attempting to access protected routes or logging in/out.

Example:

```
import { createContext, useContext, useState } from 'react';

const AuthContext = createContext({
  checkAuthStatus: () => {},
  status: 401,
  setStatus: () => {},
});

const useAuth = () => useContext(AuthContext);

const AuthProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [status, setStatus] = useState(401);

  const checkAuthStatus = () => {
    fetch(
      'http://localhost:5000/auth',
      {
        method: 'GET',
        mode: 'cors',
        headers: {
          'id_token': sessionStorage.getItem('id_token')
        }
      }
    )
      .then(response => response.status)
      .then(status => setStatus(status));
  };

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={{ checkAuthStatus, status, setStatus }}>
      {children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
};

export default AuthProvider;
export {
  AuthContext,
  useAuth
};
```

...

Wrap the `App` component.

```
import AuthProvider from "../path/to/AuthProvider";

...

<AuthProvider>
  <App />
</AuthProvider>
```

Use the `useAuth` hook to access the `status` and state updater function.

```
export default function ProtectedRoute({ redirect_path = '/login' }) {
  const { status } = useAuth();

  return status === 401
    ? <Navigate to={redirect_path} replace />
    : <Outlet/>;
}
```

...

```
const Navbar = () => {
  const { status } = useAuth();
  const is_logged_in= status === 200;

  ...

  return ....;
};
```

Login/Logout

```
const Login = ({ type }) => {
  const { setStatus } = useAuth();

  const loginHandler = (....) => {
    ...
    setStatus(200);
  };

  ...

  return ....;
};

const Logout = () => {
  const { setStatus } = useAuth();

  const logoutHandler = (....) => {
    ...
    setStatus(401);
  };

  ...

  return ....;
};
```

Use the `useEffect` hook with a dependency on the current location's `pathname` value to issue the fetch when the path is `"/"`.

```
export default function App() {
  const { pathname } = useLocation();
  const { checkAuthStatus, status } = useAuth();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (pathname === "/") {
      checkAuthStatus();
    }
  }, [pathname]);

  console.log({ status });

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Navbar />
      <ToastContainer />
      <Routes>
        <Route index element={<Home />} />
        <Route path="/vehicle/:id" element={<EV />} />
        <Route element={<ProtectedRoute />}>
          <Route path="/add" element={<AddEV />} />
        </Route>
        <Route path="/filter" element={<Home />} />
        <Route path="/compare" element={<Home />} />
        <Route path="/login" element={<LoginRegister type="login" />} />
        <Route path="/register" element={<LoginRegister type="register" />} />
        <Route path="/logout" element={<Logout />} />
        <Route path="*" element={<p>Nothing here: 404!</p>} />
      </Routes>
    </div>
  );
}
```